# Arabic Text in html coming as question marks in blackberry webview

Tags: html, blackberry, character-encoding, arabic, blackberry-webworks

I m basically an iOS developer and now i m doing blackberry development and i need to show a html string having arabic characters inside a webview(browser) in BB. But it is displaying as question marks in webview for all arabic characters.

below is the html string,

```
<html lang="ar"><head><title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<body>
<article><h1><country>جمهورية فنزويلا البوليفارية</country>
</h1><content><visas><h2><title>للمواطنين القطريين الراغبين بالسفر إلى فنزويلا</title></h2><content_red>يحتاج حاملو الجوازات الدبلوماسية أو الخاصة أو العادية إلى تأشيرة دخول إلى فنزويلا</content_red><div>يجب إصدار التأشيرة من  أقرب سفارة تابعة لفنزويلا</div><hr /><h2><title>لمواطني فنزويلا الراغبين بالسفر إلى قطر</title></h2><content_red>يحتاج حاملو الجوازات الدبلوماسية أو العادية إلى تأشيرة دخول إلى دولة قطر</content_red><div>يجب إصدار التأشيرة من  أقرب سفارة تابعة لدولة قطر</div></visas></content></article></body></html>
```

In the "meta" i have tried both
meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8 and meta charset="ISO-8859-1 but still no success.. Any suggestions please...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please use like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Final//EN">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            body { direction: rtl; }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
       <article><h1><country>جمهورية فنزويلا البوليفارية</country>
</h1><content><visas><h2><title>للمواطنين القطريين الراغبين بالسفر إلى فنزويلا</title></h2><content_red>يحتاج حاملو الجوازات الدبلوماسية أو ال`enter code here`خاصة أو العادية إلى تأشيرة دخول إلى فنزويلا</content_red><div>يجب إصدار التأشيرة من  أقرب سفارة تابعة لفنزويلا</div><hr /><h2><title>لمواطني فنزويلا الراغبين بالسفر إلى قطر</title></h2><content_red>يحتاج حاملو الجوازات الدبلوماسية أو العادية إلى تأشيرة دخول إلى دولة قطر</content_red><div>يجب إصدار التأشيرة من  أقرب سفارة تابعة لدولة قطر</div></visas></content></article>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Pras do you have the arabic language installed in your handset? It can be included by plugging your device and running the Desktop Manager.